# In a Java interface, is there a way to return an enum nested in a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, enums, interface

I'm looking for a way to return an Enum type nested in a Generic class. Here's what I mean:

```
public interface MapperClass<E, D> {

    D entityToDto(E entity);

    default List<D> entitiesToDto(List<E> entities) {
        return entities.stream()
                .map(this::entityToDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    D.Enum mapString(String str);
}
```

In other words, my method `mapString()` should return an enum that is nested in the generic type `D`, is there a way to accomplish this in Java?

Comment: you could change the signature to this `public interface MapperClass<E extends Enum<E>> { E mapString(String str); }` then the impl would have to provide an enum when implementing the interface: `class Foo implements MapperClass<FooEnum> { ... }` but you can't restrict it to inner classes

Comment: Not sure if that's possible, as I have two other methods that use the generic types E and D. I will edit my original post to reflect this. Sorry for the missing information.

Comment: Since the structure and type of D are unknown, there's no way to have a field in D named Enum.  This may be a bad use case for generics, I think you might have to use the actual type here.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
public interface MapperClass<E extends Enum<Test.TestEnum>, D extends Test> {
    E mapString(String a);
    ..
}
```

Your `Test` Class:

```
public class Test {
    ..
    enum TestEnum{
        A,B,C; //for demonstration purpose
    }
  ..
}
```

Interface implementation example :

```
 MapperClass<Enum<Test.TestEnum>, Test> a=new  MapperClass<Enum<Test.TestEnum>, Test>() {
       ..
            @Override
            public Enum<Test.TestEnum> mapString(String a) {
                return Test411.A; 
            }
       ..
     }
```